# iPhone UIViewController goes under status bar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, layout, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIView` and a `UIController` view. My is standard a 320x460 view. In `applicationDidFinishLaunching` I do:

```
[window addSubview:[controller view]];
```

The weird thing is that the `UIView` goes under the status bar (like there's missing outlet). However, if I rotate iPhone to the side and then back, it shows up ok.

Is this an expected behavior (I bet I can fix it by setting offset) or am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: try simulated interface elements?

Comment: I enabled simuated status bar on window, controller and view - no luck...

Layout is corrupted when application launches in iPhone or simulator in XCode. However, it works fine in Simulator from InterfaceBuilder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is that when you add a view to a window, you need to be aware of the state of the status bar and compensate for it:

```
if showing the status bar :
   [controller view].frame = CGRectMake(0, **20**, 320, 460);
else 
   [controller view].frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, **480**);
```

this is why IB shows you a dummy status bar.

Comment: Thanks. I was already using this to fix the problem. I just wasn't sure if that's conventional way to fix it.

Comment: Great fix, but side note, **20** should be the second parameter to CGRectMake, not the first :).

Answer (score 18):

I ran into this issue when displaying a UIViewController via *presentModalViewController*.

You can get around it by manually resizing the controller's view *after* the view has appeared:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    //manually adjust the frame of the main view to prevent it from appearing under the status bar.
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    if(!app.statusBarHidden) {
        [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,app.statusBarFrame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - app.statusBarFrame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Followup: the best solution I've seen for this is to open up the nib file for your viewcontroller, select the main view, and under "Simulated User Interface Elements" set the "Status Bar" option to anything besides "Unspecified".  I can't explain what internal values are being changed, just that this solved the issue for my app.  If you do this you won't need the code in my previous answer.

Comment: app.statusBarFrame.size.height returns 0. :(

Comment: Correction (on my remark): [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height returns 0 if it is executed before something like: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO]; But after that, it returns 20.
    statusbarHeight = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height; // statusbarHeight == 20

Answer (score 5):

I add this issue today. It turned out that I had "Wants Full Screen" checked in the ViewController's Attribute inspector.

Turning off "Wants Full Screen" resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Finally, I got to this solution. Works well **for both iPhone & iPad**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    // Allocate view controller and load nib file
    if (isIPhone) {
        self.mainViewController = [[[tfdMainViewController_iPhone alloc] initWithNibName:@"tfdMainViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.mainViewController = [[[tfdMainViewController_iPad alloc] initWithNibName:@"tfdMainViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }

    // Offset correction (iPhone bug?)
    CGRect r = self.mainViewController.view.frame; 
    r = CGRectOffset(r, 0, [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height);
    [self.mainViewController.view setFrame:r];  

    [window addSubview: self.mainViewController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

P.S. For some reason view has correct height:
480 (screen height in iPhone Portrait mode) - 20 (status bar) = 460,
but failed to set vertical offset. It is pretty strange behavior, looks like bug.

Answer (score 3):

Fixes to the window didn't work for me as I had a modal view. A UIModalPresentationCurrentContext modal view. OK, here's what worked for me. I've been searching the web up and down before getting this to work.
I'm unable to move the view.frame from the parent. However in the viewWillAppear I'm able to move it down:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Move down to compensate for statusbar
    CGRect frame = parentView.navCon.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    parentView.navCon.view.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: That's "cheating"! ;-) You should "find" the height of the statusBar and not "hardcode" it to 20. What if Apple decides to change it to say 25? Then you will be off by 5px!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Interface Builder's "Simulated User Interface Elements", then you also need to make sure that you have set the flag for "Resize View From NIB" in your MainWindow nib.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in iOS 5.  One fix would be to use `wantsFullScreenLayout` in whatever view controller needs to present modally and manually layout the view always below the status bar.

http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/radar-view-frame-inconsistency-using-presentviewcontroller-wantsfullscreenlayout-yn/

http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=1758406

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually setting the application bar hidden property AFTER adding the subview? I don't imagine this is the case, but if it's set to none when you first load the view it will layout as if there isn't one, and if you then set the status bar to not hidden it will pop up on top of your view.

A possible solution is to use `[[controller view] setNeedsLayout];` after adding the subview, or possibly `[window layoutSubviews];`. I've never had a lot of success using those to fix layout problems, but since it works after a rotation it's worth a shot.

Comment: I don't set application bar hidden at any point.

Those re-layouting things didnt help...

Answer (score 0):

Even me too got the same issue. When we are using some coding for device orientation we have wrote some coding in app delegate or in our view controller. There we need to change the condition to use the orientation return YES or NO. That solved our issue.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use UINavigationController to wrap the UIViewController you, after that, set the NavigationBarHidden to the UINavigationController. It's perfect solution cause UINavigationController do handle the height of status bar in iOS 7.

Here is my code and my screen capture.

```
UINavigationController *wrapNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController] ;

[wrapNavController setNavigationBarHidden:YES] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Xcode 6, iOS7/8 solution is in to uncheck the "Under Top Bars" checkmark in the "Extend Edges" section of the View Controller section of the Attributes Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

For Xamarin.iOS it would be:

```
if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden == false)
{
   var statusBarHeight = UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height;
   View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, statusBarHeight, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height - statusBarHeight);
}
```