# Moving custom rendered page below the status bar on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nsviewcontroller

To position my application's pages below the iOS status bar, I have created a custom renderer for my pages. It is supposed to move a page below the bar, just like the following XAML would do:

```
<local:CustomRenderedPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>
            0, 40, 0, 0
        </OnPlatform.iOS>
    </OnPlatform>
</local:CustomRenderedPage.Padding>
```

Therefore I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489367/4295410) answer which I have converted to C#.

However, without any error, the page still appears behind the status bar.
To check if the custom renderer is working I am changing the background color as well, which is working.

```
//manually adjust the frame of the main view to prevent it from appearing under the status bar.
var app = UIApplication.SharedApplication;

if (!app.StatusBarHidden)
{
    this.View.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.FromRGB(20, 100, 20); //works
    this.View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0.0, app.StatusBarFrame.Size.Height, this.View.Bounds.Size.Width, this.View.Bounds.Size.Height - app.StatusBarFrame.Size.Height); //  does not work
}

Log.WriteLine("Done");  // works
```

Am I doing something wrong, or why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

As I asked before is WHERE you call this code from and you answered "from inside my custom page renderer". But the main point is WHERE in renderer you call it.
Here is the code that works.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(MainPageRenderer))]
    namespace ButtonRendererDemo.iOS
    {
        class MainPageRenderer : PageRenderer
        {

            public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
            {
                View.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Frame.X, View.Frame.Y + 100, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this work for you? It does not for me... I was calling my code from inside the `OnElementChanged` method. However, changing the background-color works from `ViewWillAppear` as well as `OnElementChanged`.

Comment: Yes, it works for me. The result is the same as image I posted in another answer. You cannot call the code in OnElementChage because View.Frame is not populated yet.

Comment: Any idea why it is not working for me, even though the background color change does work?

Comment: I don't know. It somehow works for me BUT as I posted in comments I wouldn't try to change the frame of main view controller. I would implement custom renderer for a view and add it to the main view controller. Then I can move it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125936/discussion-between-yuri-s-and-cocoseis).

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonRendererDemo;assembly=ButtonRendererDemo"
            x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.PageWithCarousel"
             Padding="0,100,0,0">
```

[image]

Comment: That is what it is supposed to do.

Comment: what is "this" in your case? And where you call this code?

Comment: I want to move the page down. I am calling this from inside my custom page renderer.

Comment: Example uses Padding, you are trying to move the whole page. Have you tried to set padding?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to set paddings on `NSViewController`

Comment: are you using custom renderer JUST to move page down or for other purposes too?

Comment: Other purposes, too... And yes of course, I could do it in xaml, as I have stated in my question already, but my question is how to do it in code just like it is usually done on iOS. ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/2489367/4295410 )

Comment: See another answer I posted

Comment: Who "minus" that answer? It is completely working solution